# Mysql select 1 image from each category?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a SQL query to select 1 image from each category.

Both images are categories are stored into the database, in difference tables.

Does anyone know a method to do this?

Comment: I was thinking, maybe some JOIN LEFT or JOIN RIGHT would be able to do the trick?

Comment: Show your related table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT it.img_name FROM category_table ct INNER JOIN image_table it ON ct.id=it.cat_id
GROUP BY ct.id
```

This will get you one img per category. But it will not choose which,possibly a random selection...

```
SELECT it.img_name FROM category_table ct 
INNER JOIN image_table it ON ct.id=it.cat_id AND it.is_cat_default=1
GROUP BY ct.id
```

This code shows the use of a column (is_cat_default) to pick the images. Using this, you define if the image is default in the image table. Removing the `GROUP BY` statement in the last one will pick more than one image par category is there are more than one that has `is_cat_default=1`.